# react-native WebSocket & nodejs WebSocket

Tags: node.js, react-native, websocket

NodeJS:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://siteurl');

ws.on('open', function open() {
    ws.send('');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

react-native

```
let connection = new WebSocket('wss://siteurl');

connection.onopen = () => {
            connection.send('');
        };

connection.onmessage = ((event) => {
            console.log(event);
        });

connection.onerror = (event) => {
            console.log(event);
        }
```

NodeJS works fine, but react-native return 'Unable to resolve host'.
Android Stuio Emulator, started with `npm run android`.

Any ideas why it could happens?

UPD:

````
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://siteurl');
        
        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('Socket connected!');
            socket.send('');
        }

        socket.onmessage = (message) => {
            console.log(`Message:\n`, message.data);
        }
    ```
Browser works fine too
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use `socket.io-client`

[socket.io-client Document](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/)

- Example

```js
// ES6 import or TypeScript
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
// CommonJS
const io = require("socket.io-client");

// the following forms are similar
const socket = io("https://server-domain.com");
const socket = io("wss://server-domain.com");
const socket = io("server-domain.com"); // only in the browser when the page is served over https

socket.on('message', (event) => {
        console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to connect if server doesn't use socket.io? It still doesn't work with `[Error: xhr poll error]`

Comment: @DaadyDeer  The node.js server should also be unified to socket.io.